# Run lint on golang repo in travis

Tags: go, travis-ci, travis-ci-cli, golint

I run locally on my project the following command

`gometalinter --config=gometalinter.json ./...`

at the beginning I got some errors and I was fixed them all!

now I run the same command exaclty in `Travis` script 
and I got vendor errros like

```
vendor/github.com/spf13/viper/flags.go:3:8:warning: error return value not checked (could not import github.com/spf13/pflag (go/build: importGo github.com/spf13/pflag: exit status 1) (errcheck)
vendor/github.com/spf13/viper/viper.go:42:7:warning: error return value not checked (could not import github.com/pelletier/go-toml (go/build: importGo github.com/pelletier/go-toml: exit status 1) (errcheck)
```

This is the `gometalinter.json` for the config

```
{
  "vendor": true,
  "Deadline": "2m",
  "Sort": [
    "linter",
    "severity"
  ],
  "DisableAll": true,
  "Enable": [
    "gotypex",
    "vetshadow",
    "errcheck",
    "gocyclo",
    "vet",
    "golint",
    "vetshadow",
    "ineffassign",


  ],
  "Cyclo": 10,
  "LineLength": 120
}
```

I dont understand why locally I dont get this error (i've the vendor repo) and why it ask for vendor error ? what could be the reason ?

Answer (score 0):

`gometalinter` runs binaries in your path to do its check. I have had problems where my CI would have one set of binaries versions while my local development environment would have different versions.

Try updating all the required binaries on your local machine.

Comment: I run `gometalinter --install --force` and still I dont see errors locally just on travis. any idea? I use `v2.0.11` of gometalinter

Answer (score 0):

Try `--vendor` flag and check versions of `gometalinter` and all used linters.

Extract from [gometalinter documentation](https://github.com/alecthomas/gometalinter#how-do-i-make-gometalinter-work-with-go-15-vendoring):

> **How do I make gometalinter work with Go 1.5 vendoring?**
>
> gometalinter has a --vendor flag that just sets
>   GO15VENDOREXPERIMENT=1, however the underlying tools must support it.
>   Ensure that all of the linters are up to date and built with Go 1.5
>   (gometalinter --install --force) then run gometalinter --vendor ..
>   That should be it.

Comment: Thanks I've tried it  `run gometalinter --install --force` and still when I run locally I dont get any error, just when I run it on Travis. what is strange is that I run it with --vendor in travis and also in the config json and still I got the warnings on vendor packages..., any idea, hint what it could be ?

Comment: check version of `errcheck` in local env and travis